# Trying to remove cookies in Firefox 32 Developers Console doesn't work

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using Firefox 32 on MacOsx

After running "Cookie list" command in the dev console, I see a list of cookies.
However, "Edit" and "Remove" buttons don't work at all.

Is there a known issue with this?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking the "edit" and "remove" buttons just fills in the command in the dev console. You then need to focus and hit enter in order to execute the actual edit or remove.

Poor non-obvious design, IMHO.

(I know this question is old, but came across it while looking for a better way, thought I'd give a clear explanation).

Comment: I don't think it's non-obvious if you think of it like a command line.

Comment: But it's not a command line. It's a list of cookies above the command line, with widgets for edit and remove.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of open bugs for that particular issue. I just tested it in Firefox 33 and it worked fine, I was able to create/remove cookies without any problem.

If you have a particular scenario that predictably fails with Firefox 32, I advise you to file a new bug for it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Graphic%20Commandline%20and%20Toolbar).

On a side note, you might be interested in the new Storage Inspector tool that [just landed in Firefox Nightly](https://twitter.com/grssam/status/506675405718171648). It is read-only for now, but will soon allow edition too. It allows to inspect cookies, indexedDB, local and session storage.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out previously these buttons just fills up the command for you but this isn't really a nice and clear way to work with cookies.

You should try out a tool like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com). In its Cookies tab you can just right click a cookie to manipulate it (clear/delete/edit etc.).